# Store Large JSON and retrieve it quickly for binding a treeview

Tags: c#, sql, json, local-storage

I have a large JSON string ~0.5 MB that is constructed from a database table. The database table has a parent child relationship based on which I construct the JSON and use it to bind to a Tree View. I have a Console application in C# that would query the database table, generate the JSON and store it in a static JS file which I use to bind to Tree View. I use file approach since the DB table changes once a month and file can be cached by browser.

So far all is good. The problem is every time I do a CRUD on database table, I have to manually run the console application and update the JS file with new JSON.

What will be the best approach to keep the database table and file in sync with no lag or manual intervention?

Comment: Give us some code, please.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I am using the Database + Local Storage approach. I store the entire JSON in a database table. Anytime, I do a CRUD operation, I will create a new record in the database table which will also give me a new version number.

The page consuming this JSON will always check the local storage for the right version number and data. If it exists, it loads the data from local storage or else it will get the data from DB.

If anyone needs some code, then let me know.